# Set time interval as per given structure below

Tags: sql

Table Structure may be like this.

```
S.no  Time Interval                      no of keys

1     8:00 AM - 8:10 AM(ENTRY STARTS)      66

2     8:10 AM- 8:20 AM                     6

3     8:20 AM - 8:30 AM                    43

....

Nth   3:50PM - 4:00 PM(LAST ENTRY FOR REPORT)
```

How can I do this using an SQL query and I want to use it in ASP.NET GridView?

Using the below data, now I am trying to put the number of keys between the start time of workdatetime and last of this workdatetime.

NOTE: Time Interval is changed, don't worry

I'm unable to put the NO OF KEYS between the Time Interval.

I want to show the structure same as above only add one column number of keys with respect to the time interval.

```
WorkdateTime    ************    NoOfKeys
16:52:04    ************    54
16:52:06    ************    0
16:52:07    ************    2
16:52:25    ************    0
16:52:26    ************    0
16:52:35    ************    0
16:52:35    ************    0
16:53:15    ************    0
16:53:55    ************    0
16:54:28    ************    11
16:54:35    ************    0
16:55:15    ************    0
16:55:55    ************    0
16:56:35    ************    0
16:57:15    ************    0
16:57:28    ************    103
16:57:55    ************    0
16:58:35    ************    0
16:58:39    ************    2
16:59:09    ************    19
16:59:15    ************    0
16:59:42    ************    40
16:59:43    ************    2
16:59:55    ************    0
17:00:35    ************    0
17:01:15    ************    0
17:01:35    ************    4
17:01:55    ************    0
17:02:35    ************    0
17:03:15    ************    0
17:03:55    ************    0
17:03:58    ************    2
17:04:24    ************    3
17:04:35    ************    
17:05:15    ************    0
17:05:40    ************    0
17:05:46    ************    14
17:05:47    ************    0
17:05:50    ************    2
17:06:30    ************    0
17:06:37    ************    1
17:07:10    ************    0
17:07:50    ************    0
17:08:12    ************    1
17:08:30    ************    0
17:09:10    ************    0
17:09:27    ************    42
17:09:50    ************    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below query. The solution uses CTE to generate all time ranges between a start time and end time and `LEFT JOIN`s with workdatetime data table:

```
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME

SET @mindate = '08:00 AM'
SET @maxdate = '05:00 PM'



;WITH cte(startDt, endDt)
AS
(  
    SELECT @mindate AS startDt, DATEADD(mi,10,@mindate) AS endDt 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.endDt, DATEADD(mi,10,cte.endDt) FROM cte WHERE endDt < @maxdate
)
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), startDt, 100), 7))+'-'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), endDt, 100), 7)) timerange, SUM(ISNULL(NoOfKeys,0))

FROM cte
LEFT JOIN Work w
ON w.WorkDateTime >= cte.StartDt AND w.WorkDateTime < cte.EndDt 
GROUP BY startDt, EndDt
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d1c/5)

Comment: yes the concept is correct and interval are made but the no ofkey are not set between the time interval shift. nw im trying to modify it, and u plz support me to solve this.

Comment: Ok great.. do you want sum of noofkeys which falls in each time range. If it is so then the query should work. Please check the SQL Fiddle. Sample data has just one row and it is showing up on the output resultset. Let me know if you have some other requirement.